# setof/3 inside setof/3 not working, but why?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Inspired by

[Find mutual element in different facts in swi-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582295/find-mutual-element-in-different-facts-in-swi-prolog)

I wanted to try my hand at "RDBMS operations in Prolog" (actually, this is more or less Datalog)

## Problem statement

Given a database of "actors starring in movies":

```
starsin(a,bob).
starsin(c,bob).

starsin(a,maria).
starsin(b,maria).
starsin(c,maria).

starsin(a,george).
starsin(b,george).
starsin(c,george).
starsin(d,george).
```

And given set of movies, find those actors that starred in all the movies of said set.

I first had an ugly solution, but then...

## Solution that is nice

Clarify the problem:

Sets are represented by lists without duplicates, possibly ordered.

> 1. Given a *Set of Movies* `MovIn`
> 2. ... Find the *Set of Actors* `ActOut`
> 3. ... ... Such that: Every *Actor* in `ActOut` appeared in (at least) all the movies in `MovIn`
> 4. ... ... Reformulated: The *Set of Movies* `MovAx` for any actor `Ax` of `ActOut` is a superset of `MovIn`.

[setof/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) seems to be the correct toplevel predicate. An *Ansatz* for points 1 and 2 is:

```
setof(Ax, (... MovIn ...) , ActOut).
```

If `MovAx` is the *Set of Movies* that `Ax` appeared in, we can use

- [subset/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subset/2) of 
  [library(lists)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists) or
- [ord_subset/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ord_subset/2) of
  [library(ordset)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets) ... if we can ensure evertyhing is an ordset.

Let's use the `subset/2`.

Point 4 seems to make us write:

```
setof(Ax, (..., subset(MovAx, MovIn)) , ActOut).
```

Develop the `...` ...

```
setof(Ax, ( setof(Mx,starsin(Mx,Ax),MovAx) , subset(MovIn, MovAx) ) , ActOut).
```

This seems to be it already!

The feel when there are λ Expressions but there is
no λ on the keyboard or in the syntax.

### Done!

Wrap up into predicate:

```
actors_appearing_in_movies(MovIn,ActOut) :-
   setof(Ax, ( setof(Mx,starsin(Mx,Ax),MovAx) , subset(MovIn, MovAx) ) , ActOut).
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work.

There is backtracking going on, apparently I need to wrap everything into another `setof/3`,
but why??

```
?- actors_appearing_in_movies([a,b],ActOut).
ActOut = [maria] ;
ActOut = [george].
```

### Done, take two

The following **does** work:

```
subselect(Ax,MovIn) :- 
   setof(Mx,starsin(Mx,Ax),MovAx), subset(MovIn, MovAx).
actors_appearing_in_movies(MovIn,ActOut) :- 
   setof(Ax, subselect(Ax,MovIn) , ActOut).
```

```
?- actors_appearing_in_movies([a,b],ActOut).
ActOut = [george, maria].
```

### Testing

Testing is just running a few goals.

Note that for the empty set of movies, we get all the actors. This is arguably correct: 
every actors stars in all the movies of the empty set.

```
actors_appearing_in_movies([],ActOut),permutation([bob, george, maria],ActOut),!. 
actors_appearing_in_movies([a],ActOut),permutation([bob, george, maria],ActOut),!.
actors_appearing_in_movies([a,b],ActOut),permutation([george, maria],ActOut),!.
actors_appearing_in_movies([a,b,c],ActOut),permutation([george, maria],ActOut),!.
actors_appearing_in_movies([a,b,c,d],ActOut),permutation([george],ActOut),!.
```

### Question

What did I miss in

```
actors_appearing_in_movies(MovIn,ActOut) :-
   setof(Ax, ( setof(Mx,starsin(Mx,Ax),MovAx) , subset(MovIn, MovAx) ) , ActOut).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
actors_appearing_in_movies(MovIn,ActOut) :-
    setof(
        Ax,
        MovAx^(setof(Mx,starsin(Mx,Ax),MovAx), subset(MovIn,MovAx)),
        ActOut
    ).
```

Without existentially qualifying the `MovAx` variable, you get a solution per each binding of the variable.

Sample call:

```
?- actors_appearing_in_movies([a,b],ActOut).
ActOut = [george, maria].
```

Comment: Well, that was straightforward.